# Web scraping python, empy output

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need some help with the following code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

filename = "imob_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")+".csv"
with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Localizare","Pret","Data"])

    for i in range(1,100):
        r = requests.get("https://www.imobiliare.ro/inchirieri-case-vile/brasov?pagina="+format(i))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        array_price= soup.find_all('div', class_='pret')
        array_desc=soup.find_all('h2', class_='titlu-anunt hidden-xs',text=True)
        for iterator in range(0,len(array_price)):
            localizare = array_desc[iterator].text.strip()
            pret = array_price[iterator].text.strip()

            writer.writerow([localizare, pret, datetime.datetime.now()])
```

The output is empty. Can someone give me an advice, please? Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that `array_price` actually has anything? A quick look at the page appears there's nothing with a CSS class of *price* - but rather you want where the *itemprop* attribute of the element is...

Comment: You are right, thank you. I've change to "pret". Still not working.

Comment: The code raises an error `IndexError: list index out of range` for the line `localizare = array_desc[iterator].text.strip()` - array_desc is empty, please check validate it is calculated correctly

Comment: Hey @Cristina did you have a chance to check my answer?

Comment: Hei @Sarcoma. Sorry for replaying so late... thank you for your answer, it worked. However, I need the class of price. Those two are not similar...

Comment: There is no `class` price in those pages, there is an `item-prop="price"`, but no `class="price"`. The `item-prop="price"` contains `class="pret-mare"` which is the price shown on the item listing. Can you clarify what data you are looking for?

Comment: <div class="pret" itemprop="price"> includes the currency, class="pret-mare" is just for the amount, withot the currency type.

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of issues:

First as stated in the comments the class `price` does not exist. You could use `pret` but it's easier to use `soup.find_all('span', class_="pret-mare")`

Second `array_desc=soup.find_all('h2', class_='titlu-anunt hidden-xs',text=True)` is returning empty. I removed `text=True` and it started working.

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

filename = "imob_" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")+".csv"
with open(filename, "w+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Localizare","Pret","Data"])

    for i in range(1,100):
        r = requests.get("https://www.imobiliare.ro/inchirieri-case-vile/brasov?pagina="+format(i))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        array_price = soup.find_all('span', class_="pret-mare")
        array_desc=soup.find_all('h2', class_='titlu-anunt hidden-xs')
        for iterator in range(0,len(array_price)):
            localizare = array_desc[iterator].text.strip()
            pret = array_price[iterator].text.strip()

            writer.writerow([localizare, pret, datetime.datetime.now()])
```